# Nexus 7 Camera issue

Tags: android, camera, nexus-7

I have a custom camera view that extends SurfaceView. Sets the following params. The images appear blurred on Nexus 7 Generation 2 Back Camera that has a 5 MP camera. These are the following parameters that I am setting for the Camera. I don't have this issue at all on phones and other tablets. Please help

```
Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
parameters.setAntibanding(Camera.Parameters.ANTIBANDING_AUTO);

List<String> flashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
if (flashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO)) {
    parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
} else if (flashModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON)) {
    parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
}
parameters.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_AUTO);
parameters.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO);

parameters.setJpegQuality(80);

parameters.setPictureSize(2560, 1920); // Values for Nexus 7, These are dynamically calculated
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Comment: have you tried to call autoFocus ? after triggering auto focus callback, still blurred?

Comment: yes I am using autoFocus and capture the image on auto focus call back. In fact it all works well on all the devices. I am facing problem only with Nexus 7 with Back Camera

Comment: You mean that if you compare a picture captured by your app with one captured by the Camera app in same conditions, your's looks worse?

Comment: yes that's right. The one taken with my app looks worse.